# Ball picking with replacement related problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There are 31 blue and 2 red balls in a basket.

Initially you are given 3 draws to pick a ball randomly with replacements.

If you pick a red ball then your remaining draws count is increased up to 3.

Maximum turns are limited to 12. That means if you pick a red ball on 12th draw you are not getting anymore turns.

The game ends when total number of draws reach 12 or you pick 3 blue balls consecutively.

How do I calculate the average number of red balls picked per game?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R(n)$ be the expected number of red balls to be drawn in the future, if $n$ balls have been drawn already, and the last ball drawn was red.  Define $B_1(n)$ similarly, in the case that the last ball drawn was blue, and the one before it was red.  Finally, define $B_2(n)$ similarly if the last two balls were both blue.  Let $p=2/33$ be the probability of drawing a red ball, and let $q=1-p.$

After the first $3$ draws, we have on average drawn $3p$ red balls, and counting the cases, we find that the expected number of red balls in the game is $$3p+(p^3+2p^2q+pq^2)R(3)+(p^2q+pq^2)B_1(3)+pq^2B_2(3)\tag{1}$$

Now suppose that the last ball drawn was red, if $n<12$ we have $$R(n)=p(1+R(n+1))+qB_1(n+1)\tag{2}$$ because with probability $p$ draw a red ball, and then the last ball drawn was red, and with probability $q,$ we draw a blue ball, and $B_1$ applies.  Similarly,
$$\begin{align}B_1(n)&=p(1+R(n+1))+qB_2(n+1)\tag{3}\\
B_2(n)&=p(1+R(n+1))\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
We know that $$R(11)=B_1(11)=B_2(11)=p\\$$ and using the above formulas, we can work backwards to get $R(3),B_1(3),B_2(3)$ which will allow us to calculate the expected number of red balls from $(1).$

**EDIT**

Here is some more explanation of the formulas.

Look at $(2)$ first.  Here the last ball drawn was red, and $n$ balls have already been drawn, and we're computing the number of red balls we expect to draw in the future.  This is the average number of red balls on the very next draw, plus the average we draw after that.  The average on the next draw is just $p$.  The average in the future is either $R(n+1)$ or $B_1(n+1),$ depending on whether we draw a red ball or a blue ball.  We have to weight these by their respective probabilities, $p$ and $q$.

Nearly identical reasoning applies in $(3)),$ the only difference being that, if we draw a blue ball, then the last two draws were blue, so we use $B_2(n+1)$ instead of $B_1(n+1).$

Finally, in $(4)$ the last two balls were blue, so if we draw a blue ball, the game ends.

By the way, I got an average of just over $\frac15.$

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. Could you please elaborate on how you arrived at equation 1 please?

Comment: I've corrected my mistake.  Is it clearer now?  There are $8$ possible outcomes for the first $3$ draws, and you just have to classify them and compute the probabilities.

Comment: There is a typo in the equation for $R(n)$: $B_1$ is missing.

Comment: @saulspatz Should I sum up eq 1 for n=1 to 11 to get the average? Is there a typo as N74 mentioned?

Comment: @N74 Thanks.  Fixed now.

Comment: @jorel No, you don't need to sum anything.  The formulas are computing the average.  I'll add a bit more explanation to my answer.

Comment: I think there is still an error: no need for $(n+1)$ before $B_1$ on the same equation.

Comment: @N74 Thanks again.  I'm a terrible proofreader!